# Invalid field count when uploading CSV to a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I tried uploading non-English text to my Data Extensions but the system is throwing error named "Invalid Field Count".

Comment: Please update your question with a couple of rows of your import file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invalid field count means you have a delimiter problem.

There's no technical limitation preventing you from storing non-English data in a Data Extension.

I recommend using tab-delimited files.

Comment: I would also recommend that the tab-delimited file be UTF8.